# Trouble getting Data from a form to the model MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

The Code From my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.strlist)
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

The Code From my Model:

```
public class CommentClass
{
    public ArrayList strlist = new ArrayList();
}
```

The Code From my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendChat()
{
    return View("~/Views/Room/Chat.cshtml");
}
```

I have looked and I can't find anything simple on how to get my data from that textbox on my form to populate the list.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so, you put an arraylist into a textbox? Odd to start with, but ok. Then, you post the form, but your action method does not accept any parameters, so it ignores any data that's sent to it. You have to define it like this: `public ActionResult SendChat(MyModel model) {` where MyModel is the same class as whatever your model is in your view. Working through the most basic MVC tutorial would have shown you how to do this, I think.

Comment: I am very new to MVC so take this with a grain of salt.. but it does not look like you are sending any values into your controller when you try to `POST` after trying to submit data in your View.  Shouldn't you be sending your value into `SendChat()`, adding it to your model, then reloading the page?

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials or buy yourself a good book. - `strlist` is an `ArrayList` and you cannot bind a textbox to complex objects or collection (only to simple properties). Its also a field, not a property and you cannot bind to fields.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning, This is just some sudoCode

Based on my and Adyson's comments, you need to do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendChat(CommentClass comment) 
{
    comment.strList.Add( <insert your new comment here> );
    return View("~/Views/Room/Chat.cshtml");
}
```